# Searching multiple patterns in multiple DNA sequences in biostring package

Tags: r, string

let's for example I have 3 sequences

```
myseq=DNAStringSet(c("ATGACGAACTGTAAAGGACTGCACGGCC",
                     "TCCAACGAGAAAACCTGTGGGCACGGCCAAAACTGTTGGG",
                     "GGCGGGGACAAATGTTCCATGACTGGCCTTTAAAGGCCTAGAT"))
```

and the patterns I need to search are

```
fragments= DNAStringSet(c("ACTG","AAAA"))

counts=vcountPDict(fragments,myseq)
```

I want to compile the information in the form of a table with headings DNA seq, fragment and count for fragment in different columns so it can be presented well.

Comment: Probably use `sapply` or `lapply` to loop through the search terms. I'm unfamiliar with how `vcountPDict` works. If it is not vecotrized, then you may need to use two of these apply functions.

Comment: its not working.....

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you trying to create a vector of counts for each time a DNA series appears? Are you trying to plot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(Biostrings)
myseq = DNAStringSet(c(
    "ATGACGAACTGTAAAGGACTGCACGGCC",
    "TCCAACGAGAAAACCTGTGGGCACGGCCAAAACTGTTGGG",
    "GGCGGGGACAAATGTTCCATGACTGGCCTTTAAAGGCCTAGAT"
))

fragments = DNAStringSet(c("ACTG","AAAA"))
counts = vcountPDict(fragments, myseq)

# then use command of expand.grid and name two of the columns
a = expand.grid(seqID = myseq, pattern = fragments)

# Another variable to account for the frequency of each pattern 
b = expand.grid(freq = counts)
r = cbind.data.frame(a, b)
```

The result is

```
> r
                                        seqID pattern freq
1                ATGACGAACTGTAAAGGACTGCACGGCC    ACTG    2
2    TCCAACGAGAAAACCTGTGGGCACGGCCAAAACTGTTGGG    ACTG    0
3 GGCGGGGACAAATGTTCCATGACTGGCCTTTAAAGGCCTAGAT    ACTG    1
4                ATGACGAACTGTAAAGGACTGCACGGCC    AAAA    2
5    TCCAACGAGAAAACCTGTGGGCACGGCCAAAACTGTTGGG    AAAA    1
6 GGCGGGGACAAATGTTCCATGACTGGCCTTTAAAGGCCTAGAT    AAAA    0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just asked a question like this here [How to take a word and create an indicator variable based on the word's presence in comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658614/how-to-take-a-word-and-create-an-indicator-variable-based-on-the-words-presence?noredirect=1#43659054)

```
fragment <- c("ACTG","AAAA") 
sequence <- c("ATGACGAACTGTAAAGGACTGCACGGCC",
              "TCCAACGAGAAAACCTGTGGGCACGGCCAAAACTGTTGGG",
              "GGCGGGGACAAATGTTCCATGACTGGCCTTTAAAGGCCTAGAT")

sequence <- data.frame(sequence, sapply(fragment, function(i) as.numeric(grepl(i, sequence))))     
sequence
                                      sequence ACTG AAAA
 1                ATGACGAACTGTAAAGGACTGCACGGCC    1    0
 2    TCCAACGAGAAAACCTGTGGGCACGGCCAAAACTGTTGGG    1    1
 3 GGCGGGGACAAATGTTCCATGACTGGCCTTTAAAGGCCTAGAT    1    0
```

From here you can go and do

```
seq.counts <- colSums(sequence[,2:3])
seq.means  <- colMeans(sequence[,2:3])
```

Or you can do

```
sequence <- data.frame(sequence, sapply(fragment, function(i) str_count(sequence, i)))
```

Which results in

```
> sequence
                                     sequence ACTG AAAA
1                ATGACGAACTGTAAAGGACTGCACGGCC    2    0
2    TCCAACGAGAAAACCTGTGGGCACGGCCAAAACTGTTGGG    1    2
3 GGCGGGGACAAATGTTCCATGACTGGCCTTTAAAGGCCTAGAT    1    0
```

and you can use `colSums` or `colMeans`.

Comment: with due respect, sir i tried the option first option given by you, but as you see the frequency count is not accurate....